# How to write SQL query for extracting 50 percent of records from a table?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group, sql-limit

How to retrieve 50% of records in ANSI SQL. In MS SQL Server we have `Top` with percent. But I want to get in Oracle and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Would you care to add 1) table structure 2) sample data, and 3) the expected result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54957288/in-postgresql-how-to-select-top-n-percent-of-rows-by-a-column

Comment: @Jim Jones, Its a genric question. I think no need of sample data,table structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Postgres, one option uses `percent_rank()`. Assuming that `id` is your ordering column:

```
select *
from (select t.*, percent_rank() over(order by id) prn from mytable t) t
where prn <= 0.5
```

This would also work in Oracle, but for that database I would prefer a `fetch` clause:

```
select *
from mytable t
order by id
fetch first 50 percent rows only
```

Comment: As a side note: internally the `fetch first 50 percent` is translated to `select * from (select row_number() over (order by id) as rn, count(*) over () as total) where rn <= (total * 50/100)`

Comment: @GMB ,Your query is working. Will you help me ,how to write same query in Data warehouse.

Comment: why wouldn't that same query work in a data warehouse?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith,This keywords are not available in Data warehouse like hive.

Comment: Keywords are not genric in all sql like oracle,MS sql, postgresql,etc.,  I am working on hive, But facing issue to replicate the same.

Comment: then mark your question as for Hive - many data warehouses are implemented in oracle and the same SQL works in any of them

Comment: also you specified ANSI, and the fetch first is ANSI SQL syntax https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30455/271

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, Every data warehouse  allow ANSI sql syntax, to get generic syntax i have marked ANSI.

Comment: Hive gives you a SQL-like interface...not sure it has a complete ANSI SQL implementation

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you say how this would work when the total records are odd? I tried this with 5 records. This returned 3 records, I was expecting it to return 2(5/2).