# how to achieve 'select top n percentage' (like in MSSQL) in postgresql

Tags: sql, select, database-migration, postgresql-10

Have a code in **MSSQL**

```
SELECT     TOP 100 PERCENT Acct, Currency, COUNT(Name) AS NB
FROM        Details
GROUP BY Acct, Currency
```

Please help me by providing the equivalent code in **PostgreSQL.**

Comment: That seems totally useless. `top 100 percent` is the same as "all rows"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql : How do I select top n percent(%) entries from each group/category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626036/postgresql-how-do-i-select-top-n-percent-entries-from-each-group-category)

Answer (score 0):

In any database, you would just use:

```
SELECT Acct, Currency, COUNT(Name) AS NB
FROM Details
GROUP BY Acct, Currency;
```

The `TOP 100 PERCENT` is a no-op.  It just returns all the data that would be returned anyway.